# How to construct dummy matrix with a list of data

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, dummy-variable

The sample data is like this:

data1:

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | -1 | -1 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | -1 | -1 | -1 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | 3 | -1 | -1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

`data1[,1]` means that `data1[,1]` belongs to group `x1,x2,x3,x4`.
`-1` means that there is a blank.
`0` means that the data does not belong to the corresponding group(i.e. if `0` is in `x1`, which means the datum does not belong to group `1`.)
`NA` means missing data, where `NA` will randomly appear in the dataset.

**Edit:**
For example, in 1st row,
`[1,2,3,4]` means the first, second, third, and fourth columns.
Therefore, in the 1st row of data2, the row will be
`[1,1,1,1]`.

In 1st row,
`[2,3,-1,-1]` means the second and third columns, `-1` means that there is a blank.
Therefore, in the 1st row of data2, the row will be
`[0,1,1,0]`.

My expected outcome is :

data2:

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

My code is as  below:

```
for (i in 1:8){
if(data1$x1[i] %in% c(0)) {
  data1[i,] = as.list(rep(0,4))
}
else if(is.na(data1$x1[i]))
  {data1[i,] = as.list(rep(NA,4))
}}


for (i in which(data1$x1 %nin% c(NA,0))){
  for (j in 1:4){
  if (data1[i,j]<15 & data1[i,j]>0){
      data1[i,j] =  m
      data1[i,m] = 1
    }
  }
}

#replace -1 to 0
data1[data1== -1] = 0

#This for loop creates dummy matrix

for (i in which(data1$x1%nin%c(NA,0))){
  m = data1[i,] 
  m = m[m>0] 
  for(j in 1:length(m)){
    data1[i,m] = 1
  }
}

#replace the number that greater than zero to zero
data1[data1>1] = 0
```

I wonder if there is any function can be used to replace forloop. Please give me some suggestion, thank you!

Update:

The solution that using purrr::map:

```
data1 = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,2,3,-1,-1,NA,NA,NA,NA,
             rep(0,4),1,-1,-1,-1,
             rep(NA,4),
             4,3,-1,-1,
             rep(0,4)),ncol = 4,byrow = T)

map(split(t(data1), rep(1:nrow(data1),each = ncol(data1))), 
            \(b){v = b[which(b>0|is.na(b))]
                 if(sum(is.na(v))==0){
                  b[setdiff(c(1:length(b)),v)] = 0
                  b[v] = 1} else{
                  b[which(is.na(v))] = NA  
                  b[which(!is.na(v))] = 1}
                 return(b)}) %>% do.call(rbind,.)
```

Comment: Please explain the logic by which data1 is transformed into data2, it isn't exactly clear based on the code.

Comment: Taking your NA rows as separators, you have it seems different rules for change for rows 1:2, 4:5, 7:8. 7:8 appears to say if 0 0 elseif  <0 1, 4:5 says if !0 0,  1:2, well there's no logic, row wise or column wise that accounts for your expected values there.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it can provide enough information...

Comment: @gczday I think this is still challenging to interpret...for your second row of `data1` you have 2, 3, -1, -1; does this mean that 2 and 3 represent the second and third columns (matching x2 and x3 column names) for your expected outcome? And if so, how does the -1, -1 translate to zeros in columns 1 and 4? Does this imply that all other values in the row become 0 once there are matches found in the same row? It might help to clarify the first couple of rows, how each value is determined, step by step.

Comment: That is what I mean, thank you for your suggestion. Two examples were added. I hope it clarifies the first couple of rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not entirely sure of logic, but this might be helpful. Using `apply` you can evaluate each row independently.

First, create a vector of `NA`. Then, where a value is greater than 1, set that element in the vector (column number) to 1.

Second, if the vector has at least one 1 value, then change the others missing to 0.

Third, if all elements are zero and no values are missing, then make all values in that row 0.

The end result is a matrix in this example.

```
t(apply(
  data1,
  MARGIN = 1,
  \(x) {
    vec <- rep(NA, length(x))
    vec[x[x > 0]] <- 1
    if (any(vec == 1, na.rm = T)) vec[is.na(vec)] <- 0
    if (any(!is.na(x)) & all(x == 0)) vec <- rep(0, length(x))
    vec
  }
))
```

**Output**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    1    0
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    0    0    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0    0
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[7,]    0    0    1    1
[8,]    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try my best to describe the logic behind the question next time. Sorry for the inconvenience I caused